# tp5 Db:: update cannot effect

Tags: php, mysql

```
$order = db('booking_recharge')-> where('order_no',$order_no) -> where('status','0') -> find();
                    if($order){
                        file_put_contents('record_order.txt',$order);
                        Db::startTrans();
                        try {
//transection --1
                                Db::name('booking_recharge')
                                    -> where('id',$order['id'])
                                    -> update(array(
                                        'pay_price'=>$data['data']['object']['amount_total'] * 0.01,
                                        'pay_time' => time(),
                                        'status' => '1',
                                        'payment_intent'=>$payment_intent
                                    ));
                                // Db::execute("UPDATE `fa_user` SET 'surname'='will--test' WHERE `id` = 72");
                           
                                $vip = db('booking_vip') ->where('id',$order['vip_id'])-> find();
                                $up_user['level'] = $vip['level'];
                                $parent = db('user') -> where('id',$user['invite_id']) -> find();
                                if($parent){
                                    $out_money = 0;
                                    if($vip['level'] == 4){ 
                                        $config = get_addon_config('booking');
                                        if($config['vvip_ti'] > 0){
                                            $out_money = bcmul($vip['price'],$vip['share_money']*0.01,2);
                                            $up_inv['out_money'] = bcadd($parent['out_money'],$out_money,2);
                                        }
                                    }
    // ---testing update --will
                                    if($out_money > 0)
                                    {
//transection --2
          Db::name('user') -> where('id',$parent['id']) -> update($up_inv);
//transection --3
                                       
                                        $log2 = array(
                                            'user_id' => $parent['id'],
                                            'money' => $out_money,
                                            'before' => $parent['out_money'],
                                            'after' => $up_inv['out_money'],
                                            'memo' => 'push',
                                            'createtime' => time()
                                        );
                                        Db::name('user_outmoney_log') -> insert($log2);
                                        // db('user_outmoney_log') -> insert($log2);
                                    }
                                }
                                //--will
                                $giveMoney="0";
                                switch($vip['level'])
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        $giveMoney="58";
                                    break;
                                    case 2:
                                        $giveMoney="1000";
                                    break;
                                    case 3:
                                        $giveMoney="10000";
                                    break;
                                    case 4:
                                        $giveMoney="29999";
                                    break;
                                }
                                    $up_user['money'] = bcadd($user['money'],$giveMoney,2);
                                    if($vip['level'] == 4)
                                    { 
//transection --4
                                      $up_user['yue'] =  bcadd($user['yue'],"2999",2);
                                        $yue_log = array(
                                            'user_id' => $order['user_id'],
                                            'money' => 2999,
                                            'before' => $user['yue'],
                                            'after' => $up_user['yue'],
                                            'memo' => 'push',
                                            'createtime' => time()
                                        );
                                        Db::name('user_yue_log') -> insert($yue_log);
                                    }
                                    file_put_contents('user_id.txt',$order['user_id']);
                                    $sql=Db::name('user') 
                                    -> where('id',$order['user_id']) 
                                    -> fetchSql(true) 
                                    -> update($up_user);
                                    file_put_contents('fetchSql.txt',$sql);
//transection --5
                                    $money_log = 
                                    array(
                                        'user_id' => $order['user_id'],
                                        'money' => $giveMoney,
                                        'before' => $user['money'],
                                        'after' => $up_user['money'],
                                        'memo' => 'gif',
                                        'createtime' => time()
                                    );
                                    Db::name('user_money_log') -> insert($money_log);
                            Db::commit();
                        }
                        catch (\Exception $e)
                        {
                            file_put_contents('vip_exception.txt',$e);
                            Db::rollback();
                        }
```

I can see that only the first transaction is effective, while transactions 2-5 do not produce any changes. Despite the absence of errors or exceptions, the issue persists. It might be related to transaction isolation levels or commit/rollback handling. Please review your transaction management logic to ensure proper commit after each transaction and verify the isolation levels in use.

Comment: There is only one transaction that may contain multiple updates.

Comment: So you mean that I should set transaction for each update?

Comment: That depends on your business requirements.

Comment: there's a recall function for stripe. The code could run without any issue anywhere else. Except to this area.....